# Python list change index value of one after duplication

Tags: python, list, variables, reference, variable-assignment

As a hypothetical example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[0] = 4
>>> b
[4, 2, 3]
>>> a
[4, 2, 3]
```

I know that this occurs because the references to both `a` and `b` are identical, and therefore point to the same bytes of memory. A change in the bytes referenced by `b` will be reflected in `a`, since they share the same memory.

What is the best way to work around this, so that `a` remains the original value, and after `b` is made from `a`, changes to `b` will not go to `a`, also.

Specific code:

```
outputs = []
a = [[0,2,5],[4,2,0],[6,0,0]]
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    if not a[i][j]:
      b = a
      b[i][j] = 1
      outputs.append(b)
```

This returns:

```
outputs = [[[1,2,5],[4,2,1],[6,1,1]],
           [[1,2,5],[4,2,1],[6,1,1]],
           [[1,2,5],[4,2,1],[6,1,1]]]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Comment: flag as a duplicate if you believe it is one, @Paul you can vote to close.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601269/how-to-make-a-completely-unshared-copy-of-a-complicated-list-deep-copy-is-not

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the original list by slicing it:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a[:]
```

Or using the built in list list() funtion:

```
b = list(a)
```

You could also use list comprehension in place of your nested for loops:

```
b = [[i if i else 1 for i in j] for j in a]
```

Comment: I have updated, the original answers were addressing the hypothetical situation you originally posted

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
new_list = list(old_list)
```

And so this will happen -

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> b.append(8)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 8]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: What about nested lists? This technique makes a shallow copy.

Comment: For nested lists - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845152/deep-copy-nested-list-without-using-deepcopy-function