# python copying nested lists

Tags: python, list, copy, package

Let's say i have list `a`, and i want to copy it to `b` so that i can alter `a` but have its original form intact:

I use the traditional `list()` function...

```
a = [1,[2,3],4]
b = list(a)

print id(a), id(b) 
# 2941136 35748600
```

a and b have different id, so the copying is a success. but `list()` did not copy the sublist -- altering `a[1][0]` will change `b`

```
a[1][0]=3
print b
# [1, [3, 3], 4]
```

I'm aware of `copy.deepcopy()` to solve this sort of problem, but i'm wondering if there are other ways of handling this without using a module.

Comment: copy.deepcopy() is the way to go, why you need another way?

Comment: I would just use deepcopy(), but alternatively you could iterate the items of a and add them to b one at a time. That's a slow process for big lists. for item in a: b.append(copy.copy(a)). You still use copy, but not deep copy.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845152/deep-copy-nested-list-without-using-deepcopy-function

Comment: You could recursively copy but why would you not want to just use deepcopy? Is this for an actual purpose or just curiosity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to copy nested lists (given your example) is:

```
def deepcopy_nested_list(data):
    out = []
    for el in data:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            out.append(deepcopy_nested_list(el))
        else:
            out.append(el)
    return out
```

This function copies the list to a new list and then recursively copies all nested lists to achieve a deep copy.

Please note that this does only create copies of lists and immutable objects (e.g., `dicts` are not copied). It shows only the idea how you would implement such a function and does not give a full implementation.

In real world code you would of course use `copy.deepcopy()`.